# Merge numbers at same level

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a number of integers in a list, now I am working on a task where I can sum two numbers ifthey are same and add that back to my list in next step.

Now I want to find out how many numbers will remain after doing all merge operations.

**Example 1:**

```
My list contains - 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2.

Step 1: 

1   1   2   2   3   3

Step 2:     
2   4   6

So I have 3 elements in the end which is 2,4,6 in this case
```

**Example 2:**

```
My list contains: 1, 2, 1

Step 1:
1   1   2

Step 2: 
2   2

Step 3: 
4

So I have only 1 element in the end which is 4 in this case
```

I have come up with below code:

```
public static int process(List<Integer> nums) {
    Collections.sort(nums);
    Integer num1 = nums.get(0);
    Integer num2 = nums.get(1);
    while (num1 == num2) {
        nums.remove(num1);
        nums.remove(num2);
        nums.add(num1 + num2);
        Collections.sort(nums);
        if (nums.size() > 1) {
            num1 = nums.get(0);
            num2 = nums.get(1);
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
    return nums.size();
}
```

This code is working only for example 2 but not for 1, as in my logic I am directly adding element back to my nums immediately when I see two same numbers.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You're only looking at the first two elements of the sorted list, when you should be iterating over it and checking if the next element is equivalent to the current element. You'd have a better time if you build a new `List` each iteration.

Comment: Use a Map for this task, it's a lot easier and doesn't need to sort the list either.

Comment: This code does not work, since in iteration 3 the list looks like: 2, 3, 3, 4. And since 2 != 3 - the algorithm stops. I want to propose a different algorithm, will write it as an answer below.

Comment: @JacobG. Can you please provide a code of the approach which you are saying about using a new list evey time

Comment: @maio290, how map is useful for this program, can you please provide the approach?

Comment: I think you need 2 for loop. 1 is to hold current value and another is for comparison. Same approach as we do in sorting algos

Answer (score 3):

After all possible merging, you're left with at most one of each number.  If you do all the merges as soon as you can while processing the list, you can use a set to keep track of which numbers you have, leading to a simple and fast implementation:

```
public static int process(List<Integer> nums)
{
    Set<Integer> haveSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer n : nums)
    {
        while (haveSet.remove(n))
        {
            n *= 2; // merge
        }
        haveSet.add(n);
    }
    return haveSet.size();
}
```

Comment: Code golf award! (: Well this doesn't use recursion to keep checking after the next set is created.

Comment: The resutling set contains (by definition) only one copy of each number.  No further merging is possible, so no further checking is required.

Comment: Fascinating. When it creates the second pair it then checks if it already contains that number in the while loop.

Comment: Worth noting: the time complexity of this solution is O(n) despite the nested loops. The total number of iterations of the inner loop, across all iterations of the outer loop, is (n - 1) since that is the maximum number of "merges" that can be done on n integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test 1
        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2);
        System.out.println(process(nums));

        // Test 2
        nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1);
        System.out.println(process(nums));

        // Test 3
        nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3);
        System.out.println(process(nums));
    }

    static List<Integer> process(List<Integer> nums) {
        Collections.sort(nums);
        List<Integer> smallList;
        do {
            smallList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
                int sum = 0;
                if (i < nums.size() - 1 && nums.get(i) == nums.get(i + 1)) {
                    sum += nums.get(i);
                    i++;
                }
                if (sum > 0) {
                    sum += nums.get(i);
                    smallList.add(sum);
                } else {
                    smallList.add(nums.get(i));
                }
            }
            nums = smallList;
        } while (new HashSet<Integer>(nums).size() < nums.size());
        return nums;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 4, 6]
[4]
[1, 4, 6, 3]
```

**The explanation of** `while (new HashSet<Integer>(nums).size() < nums.size())`: A `Set` can have only unique elements i.e. it rejects all duplicate values and keeps only the unique ones. This makes it an excellent choice to compare a `Set` made using a `List` with the `List` to find if the `List` contains any duplicate elements.

Rest of the logic is straight forward. Feel free to comment in case there is any doubt.

Comment: Try `[1,2,2,3,3,3]`  it should reduce to `[1,4,6,3]`  so the answer would be `4`.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I made the exact same mistake because I misunderstood the requirement which was to reduce in pairs rather than sum up all identical values.  It is also hard to beat `Matt Timmerman's` answer which is quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I think of is that you only compare the first 2 numbers and disregard the rest of the list.

For example, considering the following

```
1   1   2   2   3   3
```

your first iteration will add the ones and the put their sum back into the list and then sort it so it will look something like this:

```
2  2   2   3   3
```

your first two elements will still match so it will add them and sort the list again resulting in this:

```
2   3   3   4
```

and after this **nums.get(0)** = 2 and **nums.get(1)** = 3 will never be equal. You should check the other elements as well.

Comment: yes that is the issue, now I want to know how to fix this

Comment: And where is the answer ?!

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad, consider reading the „Answering and moderating homework questions”  [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4153931)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution in python

**First** you need to sort your array, **then** you need to iterate over all the elements starting from index 0 up to (Array size - 2) **Which is all elements excluding the last one**

**Second**, **if** the element you are on is equal to the next, **then** you need to insert the new value which is `2 * arr[curernt_index]` at the same index you are on, and you need to slice your array, so it only includes, **All elements until your `current_index + 1`, and all the elements including `current_index + 2` until the end of the array**, and keep the index at its place.
**Else** increase the index value to point to the next element

**Last step**: sort you array again.
Java Sample Code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,1,2,3,3));
    Collections.sort(l);
    for(int idx = 0; idx < l.size() - 1; ){
      if(l.get(idx) == l.get(idx+1)){
        l.set(idx, l.get(idx) * 2);
        List<Integer> tmpList = l.subList(0, idx+1);
        tmpList.addAll(l.subList(idx + 2, l.size()));
        l = tmpList;
      } else {
        idx++;
      }
    }
    Collections.sort(l);
    System.out.println(l.toString());
  }
}
```

Python sample code:

```
l = [1,2,1]
l.sort()
idx = 0
while idx < len(l) - 1:
  if l[idx] == l[idx+1]:
    l[idx] *= 2
    l = l[:idx+1] + l[idx+2:]
  else:
    idx += 1
l.sort()
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some recursion is the best weapon against this kind of puzzles:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3));
    List<Integer> newList = list;
    do { // Do merge until 2 lists are equal (no more elements to merge
        list = newList;
        newList = merge(list);
    } while (!newList.equals(list));
    System.out.println(merge(list).toString());
}

static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer firstElement = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(firstElement)) { // aha, found pair
            result.add(firstElement * 2);
            if (list.size() > i + 1) { // check if there is something in the list after this pair
                List<Integer> tail = list.subList(i + 1, list.size());
                result.addAll(merge(tail)); // merge the rest of the list
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            result.add(firstElement);
            firstElement = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    result.add(firstElement); // add the last element
    return result;
}
```

Comment: your o/p is wrong [2, 4, 6, 3]. it should be [2, 4, 9]

Comment: @Muzzamil the task is to add only pairs. There is an odd number of number 3 - so it cannot be 9, but 6 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a second list to hold the results of your current math. Otherwise, you are performing operations on your result set during the first step and this is not what you intended.

Eg. Take a look at this:

My list contains - 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2.

Step 1 (sort):

1   1   2   2   3   3

Step 2 (remove, add and sort and repeat):
A) 2 2 2 3 3
B) 2 3 3 4

Done because 2 and 3 are not equal.

Furthermore, your algorithm will fail again if you have an odd count of the same number. Instead of sorting and comparing the first two, I suggest you iterate nums and use list searching methods such as nums.indexOf(num) to search for a match of the number in the rest of the list.

Here is a possible algorithm to use:

```
public static int process(List<Integer> nums) {
        List<Integer> output = new LinkedList<>(); //Stores the result of addition
        int result = processDuplicate(nums);

        while (result != -1) { //Loop while process duplicates finds a match
            output.add(result); //Will add the addition
            result = processDuplicate(nums); //Tries to find and process a sum again
        }

        if (output.size() == 0) { //If nothing was added to the output list, it didn't find any duplicates
            return nums.size();
        } else {
            output.addAll(nums); //Add the remaining unmatched numbers to the new list
            return process(output); //Start the finding matches again with the new list
        }
    }

    private static int processDuplicate(List<Integer> nums) {
        for (Integer num : nums) {
            int firstLocation = nums.indexOf(num); //Find the first location of the number
            int lastLocation = nums.lastIndexOf(num); //Find the second location of the number
            if (firstLocation != lastLocation) { //Make sure we found the number in two different locations
                nums.remove(num); //Remove two copies of the number and return the result of adding it to itself.
                nums.remove(num);
                return num * 2;
            }
        }
        return -1; //Signalizes there were no matches
    }
```

*Beginner Note for Modifying Collections in an Enhanced For Loop:*

*Changing the contents of a collection during an enhanced for loop will throw ConcurrentModificationException if you continue iteration after the modification. Do note, the above code works because the for loop is ended by the return statement directly after collection modification.*

Answer (score 0):

This task is pretty easy to achieve using a Map with the individual numbers as key.

```
    Map<Integer,Integer> sumMap = new TreeMap<>();
    int[] numbers = {1,1,3,3,2,2};

    for(int number : numbers)
    {
        if(sumMap.containsKey(number))
        {
            sumMap.put(number, sumMap.get(number)+number);
        }
        else
        {
            sumMap.put(number, number);
        }
    }


    for(Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : sumMap.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
```

Basically outputs: `2 4 6`

Comment: It would be best to note this solution only works for one sweep. Does it also work for the second example?

Comment: That's right, but you can always recurse ;)

Just wanted to put this in as another way to achieve this since OP asked for an example with a map after my comment.

Answer (score 0):

A Solution just Using Streams

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ex1 = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2);

        System.out.println(process(ex1));

        List<Integer> ex2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1);

        System.out.println(process(ex2));

    }

    public static List<Integer> process(List<Integer> numList) {
        if (numList.stream().distinct().count() == numList.size()) {
            return numList;
        }
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> group1 = numList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList()));

        List<Integer> result = group1.values().stream()
                .map(item -> item.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return process(result);
    }
}
```

And result

```
[2, 4, 6]
[4]
```

Comment: Hey could you add some documentation to your code, such as a comment explaining `groupingBy(Function.identity()` and just explain each line in general? The functions are hard to understand for someone who has never used streams before. Would be great to understand how it works!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the order in the list does not matter.
The drawback of previous algorithm (if we will put the correctness aside) - is that it is sorting the list after each 2 first number comparison. Which is pretty complex, `O((n*log(n))^2)` in best case scenario (sorting for half of numbers, and the list gets halved each iteration)

I think an easier solution will be to split the numbers in buckets instead of sorting, and then get pairs from there. You actually just can count the numbers, so it will be a Map where the key is the number from list and the value is the counter of that number in current iteration.
The complexity of the following algorithm is `O(n*log(n))`, since we will cut in half each iteration duplicate numbers, and each iteration goes over each remaining number.

Let's have the same example 1.

`1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2`

*Iteration 1:* 
Count all numbers of the same value and add them as entries in map.
The map will be with the following values:

```
|number|count|
|------|-----|
|  1   |  2  |
|  2   |  2  |
|  3   |  2  |
|------|-----|
```

*Iteration 2:* (and consequent iterations until stop condition is met)

Now you take all the entries in the map and perform the following while populating a new map for iteration 2:

```
1. if the values for all keys in map are equal 1 -> stop. The keys of the map are the final list
2. else: for each entry in map (key, value):
   1.1. value_mod = value mod 2
   1.2. new_count = value div 2 (integer div)
   1.1. new_key = key * 2
   1.2. if (new_count > 0) then
      1.2.1. new_map add entry new_key -> new_count 
             (or add 'new_count' to existing entry by key 'new_key')  
   1.3. end if
   1.4. if (value_mod > 0) then
      1.4.1. new_map add entry key -> 1 
             (or increment an existing entry by key 'key')
   1.5. end if
3. map <- new_map
4. end if
```

So following this algorithm we will have:

```
|number|count|
|------|-----|
|  2   |  1  |
|  4   |  1  |
|  6   |  1  |
|------|-----|
```

However, this algorithm can have more iterations, having said that, the complexity of each iteration is way lower.

For example the list:
`1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,4`

With algorithm described in the question, you will have the following iterations: (sorted list is `1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4`)

*Iteration 1:* (sorted)
`2,3,4,4,4,4,6,6,6`

*Iteration 2:* (sorted)
`2,3,6,8,8,12`

*Iteration 3:* (sorted)
`2,3,6,12,16`

With the above algorithm, the iterations will be the following:

*Iteration 1:*

```
|number|count|
|------|-----|
|  1   |  2  |
|  2   |  6  |
|  3   |  7  |
|  4   |  1  |
|------|-----|
```

*Iteration 2:*

```
|number|count|
|------|-----|
|  2   |  1  |
|  4   |  4  |
|  6   |  3  |
|  3   |  1  |
|------|-----|
```

*Iteration 3:*

```
|number|count|
|------|-----|
|  2   |  1  |
|  8   |  2  |
|  12  |  1  |
|  6   |  1  |
|  3   |  1  |
|------|-----|
```

*Iteration 4:*

```
|number|count|
|------|-----|
|  2   |  1  |
|  16  |  1  |
|  12  |  1  |
|  6   |  1  |
|  3   |  1  |
|------|-----|
```

Final list: `2,16,12,6,3` or sorted: `2,3,6,12,16`